# Inputstream error while trying to read bytes

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am converting a png image to byte array and sent it using sockets to client on android
On android i read the bytes as shown bellow:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream dataBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
int readLength;
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
while ((readLength = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
 dataBuffer.write(buffer, 0, readLength);
 }
byte bitmapdata[] = dataBuffer.toByteArray();
```

But i have a very stupid problem here. 
Java gives me error that it can not accept a byte array for in.read(buffer)
For some reason it seems that it only accepts char[], says "Can not resolve method read(byte[])".

Anyone know why is that happening or any other way i can do this ?

Comment: It's not an InputStream, it's a Reader, and that is the sum total of your problem. Too localised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java supports Unicode, a single Java `char` is at least two `byte`s long, and sometimes longer ([gory details here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)).  This means that we can't treat these data types interchangeably as we can in other languages such as C.

Since you want to deal with raw bytes, stay away from `InputStreamReader` and work directly with the `InputStream` provided by your `Socket`.

Something like this should work:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream dataBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
int readLength;
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
while ((readLength = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
  dataBuffer.write(buffer, 0, readLength);
}
byte bitmapdata[] = dataBuffer.toByteArray();
```

If you were expecting to read text instead of image data from your `Socket`, `InputStreamReader` would be the way to go, as it hides away many of the headaches relating to variable-byte character encoding formats ([more info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html))

Comment: Thank you for your help. I feel silly that I didn't manage to figure that out by my self :P

Answer (score 1):

InputStreamReader doesn't have a read.(byte[]) method. Here is an example to solve your problem : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstreamreader.html